# Laravel Vue 2 Shopingapp best approach SPA or Multi page app?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, single-page-application

this may sound a bit stupid question :). I have few questions in my mind and looking for a good answer.

1. In laravel 5.4, vue 2 comes with bundled. Most of the tutorial shows SPA app with laravel and vue 2. When people say they use laravel and vue 2 for their app does this mean they are making SPA app?
2. Is there any ways to create a Hybrid app like facebook where single page features and multi page features are available?
3. Is there any good proof that google can index SPA app (looking for a tutorial or blog but no luck till now :( )

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: It depends on you. If you want to use a laravel only for APIs then you should go with SPA. if you want to serve vueJS app through laravel then you have to use multiple page.

Comment: Thank you for the good point :)